# a4j:commandButton not work in templating jsf

Tags: jsf-2

my problem is the following, 
I have a template.xhtml that i uses for layout of the my web application

```
<div id="header">
   <ui:insert name="header">
        [Top Bar content will be inserted here]
     </ui:insert>
    </div>



    <div id="main">
        <ui:insert name="main">
            [Nav Bar Left content will be inserted here]
         </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="button">
         <ui:insert name="button">
            [Nav Bar Left content will be inserted here]
         </ui:insert>
    </div>
```

then i have a addOrder.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
template="/WEB-INF/template/popUpInsert.xhtml">

<ui:define name="header">
  <h:outputLabel value="Status" />
  <rich:inplaceInput value="#{ordineController.orderToSave.status}"   />
  <h:outputLabel value="Code" />
  <rich:inplaceInput value="#{ordineController.orderToSave.code}"  />
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="main">
  Here there is a data table that contains lines of the order
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="button">
 <h:form>
 <a4j:commandButton value="Save" action="#{ordineController.addOrder()}" />
 <h:form>
</ui:define>
```

but when i try to save the order both status and code are null , i try to change a scope to button save (execute="@all") but nothing

What's wrong?

Comment: Why have you chosen to not have any forms in your templates? Anything not wrapped in an `<h:form/>` will not get submitted to the server. So all those input components are not going to have their values processed server-side

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page `<h:messages styleClass="message" />`, you will see more warnings from JSF, in your case there should be a warning about missing forms because JSF knows which elements require to be inside one. In the end it is all HTML and JavaScript so inputs need to be inside the form if you want to do a submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the related input components in the same form as the command component. Any input components which are not in the same form as the command component are plain ignored in the submit. Note that this is a HTML restriction, not a JSF restriction.

So, this should do for you:

```
<h:form>
    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            [Top Bar content will be inserted here]
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <ui:insert name="main">
            [Nav Bar Left content will be inserted here]
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="button">
        <ui:insert name="button">
            [Nav Bar Left content will be inserted here]
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

And:

```
<ui:define name="header">
    <h:outputLabel value="Status" />
    <rich:inplaceInput value="#{ordineController.orderToSave.status}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Code" />
    <rich:inplaceInput value="#{ordineController.orderToSave.code}"  />
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="main">
    Here there is a data table that contains lines of the order
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="button">
    <a4j:commandButton value="Save" action="#{ordineController.addOrder()}" />
</ui:define>
```

Be careful that you don't create "God" forms this way.